# Vertical word wrap in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

If I have five 32x32 pixel images in a div container I can easily make them 'word-wrap' left-right and organise themselves into a row of 3 images, then a row of two:

```
<div style="max-width:96px">
  <img src="a.png"/>
  <img src="b.png"/>
  <img src="c.png"/>
  <img src="d.png"/>
  <img src="e.png"/>
</div>
```

Which results in:

```
a b c
d e
```

If I reduce the `max-width` of the div to 64px then I will see

```
a b
c d
e
```

But, is there way that I can specify a `max-height` of a div and have the images organise themselves like this:

```
a d
b e
c
```

So that if the `height` of that containing div is actually variable the 32x32 images will stack vertically until there is no room, then start a new column?

(Ideally I would have the filled columns on the right and the unfilled column to the left, but any suggestions along these lines would be appreciated).

Thanks

Comment: I found [Online Vertical Layout](http://www3.telus.net/public/lchor/ovltext2011.htm), which is heavily biased toward displaying Chinese characters, but it may be of some help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if that is entirely possible with regular (pre-v3) CSS. You're fighting against the document "flow", which will display images as inline, hence the first arrangement. You could try the [CSS columns property](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/multicolumn.html) - but that won't work in older browsers.

There may be JavaScript solutions out there as well, but I don't know of any off the top of my head.